# How To Get XSRF Token value from blogger.com to post content

Tags: python-3.x, oauth-2.0, scrapy, csrf, blogger

I have contents for blogger.com at my mongo db, and I want create python script to post the contents to blogger.com.

When I look developer console when publish a post at developer console. I need to pass some value,

```
{
   "method":"editPost",
   "params":"{\"1\":1,\"2\":\"wadaw\",\"3\":\"ffrdgd\",\"4\":\"3425436456546\",\"5\":0,\"6\":0,\"7\":1,\"9\":0,\"10\":2,\"11\":1,\"12\":[\"grdhth\"],\"13\":0,\"14\":{},\"15\":\"en\",\"16\":0,\"17\":{\"1\":2017,\"2\":12,\"3\":18,\"4\":21,\"5\":32},\"20\":0,\"21\":\"\",\"22\":{\"1\":1,\"2\":{\"1\":0,\"2\":0,\"3\":0,\"4\":0,\"5\":0,\"6\":0,\"7\":0,\"8\":0,\"9\":0,\"10\":\"0\"}},\"23\":1,\"27\":0,\"28\":0}",
   "xsrf":"AOuZoY7tEYY0lUcn9E2mDmaJil5uHpTCnw:23543543141"
}
```

When i search what is xsrf, it should be placed at hidden value / session / cookie, but I didnt't find it ?

is there any method to get xsrf value ?

actually, I have search another method to do this. Its to use blogger api, but is it possible to get oAuth2 token without google prompt ?

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is regex like:

```
"xsrf":"(.+?)"
```

Comment: no, I mean,
is there any method to get xsrf value from website ?